# С помощью какого сервиса можно реализовать перевод денег с банковской карты на банковскую карту?

Tags: платежи, банковские-карты, онлайн-коммерция

Задача у меня такая:
Нужно на сервере принимать платеж с любой банковской карты клиента и пересылать платеж исполнителю на его карту в его валюте.
Как я понял, прямой перевод сделать нельзя, но вроде можно через свой промежуточный счет?
Сейчас общаюсь со службой поддержки https://www.paymentrails.com/developers, но в его возможностях и надежности я не уверен.

Comment: А местных банков нет?

Comment: Я уже думал об этом, но большинство банков, у которых есть подобные API, работают в местной валюте, а это мне не подходит. + хочется использовать какой-нибудь единый платежный сервис для приема и отправки платежей.